# jquery array of checkbox not sent to php file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

to gather the value from the check boxes:

```
var filtersArray = $("input[@name='filters']:checked").map(function(i,n){
                        return $(n).val();
                    }).get();
```

Posting to php file

```
$.post("php/performSearch.php", {
     keywords: $('#keywords').val(), 
     'filters[]': filtersArray}, 
     function(data){
         //alert(data);
     });
```

Php doesn't get the array no matter what i do to it
I have:

```
$postedKeywords = $_POST['keywords'];
$postedFilters = $_POST['filters[]'];
```

Keywords is posted, filters[] is not. I tried print_r....no result..

I tried:

```
foreach($_POST as $val)
    echo $val;
```

I get the value of $_POST['keywords'] and Array for $_POST['filters'] So it is sent but for some reason i cannot use the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$.post(
    'php/performSearch.php', {
        keywords: $('#keywords').val(), 
        filters: filtersArray
    }, 
    function(data) {

    }
);
```

This will send a POST request that might look like this:

```
filters[]=1&filters[]=2
```

Comment: that is the solution. thank you. I read some questions here and the solution for the same problem was putting some []. I guess i wasn't supposed to.

Comment: Oh and check out the `jQuery.param()` helper function (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$.post("php/performSearch.php", {
     keywords: $('#keywords').val(), 
     'filters\[\]': filtersArray}, 
     function(data){
         //alert(data);
     });
```

Or try this too:

```
$.post("php/performSearch.php", {
     keywords: $('#keywords').val(), 
     filters: filtersArray}, 
     function(data){
         //alert(data);
     });
```

And to get in php, don't use `[]`, just use:

```
$postedKeywords = $_POST['keywords'];
$postedFilters = $_POST['filters'];
```